# Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark xmls declaration causes error "A relative URI cannot be created..."

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, themes

Following [the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/themes/dark) for adding and configuring the nuget packages for the Xamarin.Forms dark theme or light theme (which have been in preview for two years now...) includes adding the xmls declaration to the `<Application>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:dark="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Themes;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark"
             x:Class="Percebe.XF.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="dark:DarkThemeResources" />
        <ResourceDictionary>
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have this in a file named `App.xaml`, in a .NET Standard class library project shared by projects for Android, iOS, UWP, and Mac. The project includes both nuget packages required: `Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base` and `Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark`.  But Visual Studio 2017 gives me an error on the xmls:dark line: "**A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.**", and since that line failed I also get an error on my use of the "dark:" namespace further down in the `<ResourceDictionary>` element. It sounds like it doesn't see it as an absolute URL, so maybe it's not recognizing the URI protocol "clr-namespace:"? How do I fix this error?

Comment: You can try : https://medium.com/@milan.gohil/adding-themes-to-your-xamarin-forms-app-3da3032cc3a1

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Source` property to `MergedWith` will make it work:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary MergedWith="dark:DarkThemeResources" />
    ...
</Application.Resources>
```

I know we should start to use `Source` since Xamarin.Forms 3.0. But as `Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base` and `Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Dark` is still in preview, Source doesn't support the syntax like `dark:`. We still have to use `MergedWith` to utilize this feature.

Comment: haven't had a chance to try it, because of higher priority parts of the app. I'll let you know